# Unable to run JSP at remote Tomcat server

Tags: javascript

I have Tomcat7 on my remote server.
I have developed a jsp for my application and that is set as homepage.
When I run it on my local server(Localhost : Tomcat7), it is working fine.....
but I run on the remote server, it is only reading few lines of my file..but not the whole jsp.
Could anyone please help me on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post details of the exception thrown. You may need to look into tomcat/logs/catalina.out for exception trace and message. It usually happens when you have coded to populate values from database and on your live/remote server those arenot found.

Comment: It says ClassNotFoundException...........oracle.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Are you sure oracle's driver jar file is in you lib folder (WEB-INF/lib) !! If its missing, adding driver jar file would resolve the problem.

Comment: It is working fine on my local server.I have already placed the driver jar file. Only with the remote server, it is showing Exception.

Comment: would it be possible to post complete exception stacktrace

Comment: thanks all.problem solved.I have deleted the jar files and placed new jar files.Restarted the tomcat and ran my application.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe Tomcat doesn't see  your libraries like jstl (if you use tags)...

Comment: Thanks for your response.....But I have not used JSTL tags